# Spark- reading for HDFS -SIMPLE authentication is not enabled

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

I am attempting to read a file from HDFS into Spark and perform some data processing on it.
I'm trying to do it from a pod in Kubernetes.

so this is what i run :

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('myAppName').getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.yarn.keytab', '/data/conf/my.keytab')
spark.conf.set('spark.yarn.principal', 'datascience@Snir.LOCAL')
cat_df = spark.read.load("hdfs://data-main1.snir.network/process/extra/folder")
```

the error i get :
SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.load.
: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
 SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1582)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.isDirectory(FileSystem.java:1700)
    at o
... 23 more
```

**i also tried:**

spark.conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos")

but no luck.

did someone handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

Those configurations are changed:

- **Spark 2.x**: `spark.yarn.keytab` and `spark.yarn.principal`
- **Spark 3.x**: `spark.kerberos.keytab` and `spark.kerberos.principal`

Also, those need to set up **before** your Spark session is initialized, i.e.

```py
spark = (SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName('myAppName')
  .config('spark.yarn.keytab', '/data/conf/my.keytab')
  .config('spark.yarn.principal', 'datascience@Snir.LOCAL')
  .getOrCreate()
)
```

Comment: i'm still getting the same error:
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
 SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]  i have used spark 3.x. and run your code. but same error

Comment: How have you started your Spark application? via spark-submit or pyspark shell?

Comment: Hi @DevFroml : are you able to resolve this issue, if yes could you please post it as I am also facing the same issue and trying to find out the solution for it.

Comment: Has anyone figure out this issue? Same problem here..